# How to pivot certain columns and rename column at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the following table that has data on patients. Each patient can show up more than once if they have more than 1 code associated with their ID. That code is also associated with a code group which is conveyed using the CriteriaID column.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #df

CREATE TABLE #df 
(
    PTID VARCHAR(10),
    clmid VARCHAR(5),
    clmfrom date,
    Code VARCHAR(5),
    CriteriaID VARCHAR(5)
);

INSERT INTO #df (PTID, clmid, clmfrom, Code, CriteriaID)
VALUES
('X0001', '001', '2021-07-25', 'A1109', '41'),
('X0001', '001', '2021-07-25', 'B1192', '42'),
('X0002', '002', '2021-08-25', 'A1123', '41'),
('X0002', '002', '2021-08-25', 'B2231', '42'),
('X0003', '003', '2021-09-25', 'B2312', '42')

SELECT * FROM #df
```

I would like my final table to pivot Code and rename the columns based on the CriteriaID.

Essentially, I would like my final table to look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #finaldf 
(
    PTID VARCHAR(10),
    clmid VARCHAR(5),
    clmfrom date,
    SysCode VARCHAR(5),
    DiaCode VARCHAR(5),
);

INSERT INTO #finaldf (PTID, clmid, clmfrom, SysCode, DiaCode)
VALUES
('X0001', '001', '2021-07-25', 'A1109', 'B1192'),
('X0002', '002', '2021-08-25', 'A1123', 'B2231'),
('X0003', '003', '2021-09-25', NULL, 'B2312')

SELECT * FROM #finaldf
```

If CriteriaID associated with the code is 41 in #df then I would like the column to be SysCode. If the criteriaID associated with the code is 42 then I would like the column to be DiaCode. If a PTID does not have a certain CriteriaID that corresponding SysCode or DiaCode column should be NULL.

Any help would be appreciated. I believe I should be using a pivot or max function but am not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is known as conditional aggregation:

```
select ptid, clmid, clmfrom,
    Max(case when CriteriaID = 41 then code end) SysCode,
    Max(case when CriteriaID = 42 then code end) DiaCode
from #df
group by ptid, clmid, clmfrom;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. A concept I have not heard of before but this is exactly what I was looking for.